# Вызов данных переменной из другого класса JAVA

Tags: java, классы, методы

Есть два класса

```
public class mysql {

    // JDBC URL, username and password of MySQL server
    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://****:3306/ac";
    private static final String user = "***";
    private static final String password = "***";

    // JDBC variables for opening and managing connection
    private static Connection con;
    private static Statement stmt;

     public static void main(String args[]) {
         try {

            // opening database connection to MySQL server
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);

            // getting Statement object to execute query
            stmt = con.createStatement();


            String[] insert = {"INSERT INTO users(ip) VALUES (ip);"};

            for (String sql : insert) {
             stmt.execute(sql);
         }

        } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
            sqlEx.printStackTrace();
        } 
    } 
}
```

и второй класс

```
package AC;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Getip {
    public static String ip;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        URL whatismyip = new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                          whatismyip.openStream()));

        ip = in.readLine(); 
        System.out.println(ip);
    }
}
```

Нужно из класса `Getip` вытащить значение переменной `ip` и отправить по mysql в классе два. Много чего попробовал, но ничего не получается. Если кто-то знаете как сделать, прошу объяснить простым текстом, на java недавно совсем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть методы, которые называют Getter и Setter.
Первый вытаскивает значение из класса, второй, соответственно, его устанавливает.
В Вашем случае в классе Getip надо добавить метод

```
public String get_my_IP(){
   return this.ip
}
```

Во втором классе объявляем переменную

```
Getip getip;
```

и обращаемся

```
String ip = getip.get_my_IP();
```

Comment: спасибо! помогло

Answer (score 1):

Ну во-первых функция main(String [] args) это точка входа в приложение и должна быть в 1 м классе, во-вторых в ООП есть такое понятие как инкапсуляция и в случае с полями класса её обеспечивают методы getParam() и setParam(ParamType param)  где Param это имя поля. И в-третьих, чтобы получить доступ к полю другого класса нужно иметь переменную ссылающуюся на экземпляр этого класса в месте где вы хотите его получить, т.е в вашем случае в классе mysql  нужно создать экземпляр Getip , при помощи new Getip();  либо получить его каким-либо путём из другого класса.

Comment: классы находятся в разных файлах. т.к. кроме класса getip будут еще классы, которые будут собирать информацию и передавать посредством класса mysql. А вот как раз о том, как получит getip из другого класса я и думаю. Собственно говоря в этом то и есть проблема

Comment: Никакой проблемы я не вижу, если getip  это единственный экземпляр этого класса, то можете рассмотреть  паттерн singleton